# Best way for downloading many files in a website

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, web-application-design

I'm designing a website that will let the user synchronize a local folder to an online folder (Kinda like dropbox).

I'm trying to find a way to avoid developing a local tool to do the download and synchronization. And do it somehow online.

Is it possible to download multiple files in a certain directory tree?
Can a website have free write access to local directories?

A zip file is not an option, since the file batch could get pretty big.

EDIT: Synchronization shouldn't occur periodically. Just when the user logs in the website.

Comment: could use something along the lines of rsync to check every 5 minutes that directory on the local host and sync the file to the website(server)

Comment: rsync seem to be limited to filesystem (or am i wrong?), but csync might work... Thanks!

Comment: oh wait it's a linux tool - Most of my users will windows based

Comment: There are options for windows users : cwRsync, Cygwin, DeltaCopy and Unison. http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/rsync/rsync_pc1.html

Comment: I'd like to keep the user's computer as clean as possible. I was thinking of something like a feature in ASP.NET which let you save files to the client computer without a download...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use something like WebDAV then see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)